# Create new object that contains elements from original object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object with data formatted similar to the following...

```
var origData = {data: [
    ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
    ]};
```

What I'd like to do is reformat this such that the data is structured like this...

```
newData = {
    {'Header1': 0, 'Header2': 1, 'Header3': 2},
    {'Header1': 3, 'Header2': 4, 'Header3': 5},
    {'Header1': 6, 'Header2': 7, 'Header3': 8}
    };
```

Every time I try to write a possible solution, I get lost in nested `for` loops. I have a feeling I'm over-complicating this.

The header array is `origData.data[0]`.

The data arrays can be retrieved using:

```
dataArrays = [];

for (var i = 1; i < origData.data.length; i++) {
    dataArrays.push(origData.data[i]);
}
```

At this point, this is where I start getting confused. Basically, I need to construct a new object in a `for` loop that contains the header array elements as the keys, and the respective data array elements as the values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result should be an array of object rather than an object of objects:

```
newData = [
  {'Header1': 0, 'Header2': 1, 'Header3': 2},
  {'Header1': 3, 'Header2': 4, 'Header3': 5},
  {'Header1': 6, 'Header2': 7, 'Header3': 8}
];
```

Here is how you can create it:

```js
var origData = {data: [
    ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
]};

var newData = [];

// get the headers
var headers = origData.data[0];

// loop through the original data arrays
for (var i = 1 ; i < origData.data.length; i++) {

  // get the data array for this item
  var data = origData.data[i];

  // create an empty item
  var item = {};

  // combine headers with values into the item
  for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
    item[headers[j]] = data[j];
  }

  // add the item to the array
  newData.push(item);
}

// Show result in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick (untested) stab at attacking your problem:

```
var origData = {data: [
    ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
]};

var headers = origData.data[0];
var i, j;
var result = [];
var row, item;

// start from the row after the headers
for (i = 1; i < origData.data.length; i++) {
    row = origData.data[i];
    item = {}

    // assume that we've got an entry for each header in the individual rows
    for (j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        item[headers[j]] = row[j];
    }

    result.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know the header element is always at offset `0` in `origData`, you also know that in each array in the `origData` parent array, there are 3 items at indexes `0`, `1`, and `2`. Therefore you only need one loop, starting from index `1` which creates a new object referencing back to `origData` offset `0` for the header at each index and then the current iteration's object for the values.

Try this:

```
var newData = new Array(),
    obj;
for (var i=1; i<origData.data.length; i++) {
  obj = new Object();
  obj[origData.data[0][0]] = origData.data[i][0];
  obj[origData.data[0][1]] = origData.data[i][1];
  obj[origData.data[0][2]] = origData.data[i][2];
  newData.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cnrotcv/)

```
var headers = origData.data.shift();
var newData = [];
origData.data.forEach(function (arr) {
    var obj = {};
    arr.forEach(function (val, i) {
        obj[headers[i]] = val;
    });
    newData.push(obj);
})
console.log('newData',newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var origData = {data: [
    ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
    ]};
var result = [];
for (i=1; i< origData.data.length; i++){
    var obj = {};
    obj[origData.data[0][0]]=origData.data[i][0];
    obj[origData.data[0][1]]=origData.data[i][1];
    obj[origData.data[0][2]]=origData.data[i][2];
    result.push(obj);

}
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0r8envcx/2/)**